# How find this In any group of $2n-10$ persons,there are always at least $10$ persons who have the same birthdays.

Tags: probability

What is the smallest posiible integer value of $n$ such that  the following statement is always true

In any group of $2n-10$ persons,there are always at least $10$ persons who have the same birthdays.
(For this question,you may assume that there are exactly $365$ different possible birthdays.)

This SM0(2013.6,5) problem 34

Comment: What happens if there are $9 \cdot 365$ persons ? And $9 \cdot 365 + 1$ ?

Comment: I'll explain why posted question, these problems I know to do it, I just take an examination of is to share the test questions, give everyone see, also can be archived Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the pigeonhole principle.